# Gitlab - git user can't execute git commands

Tags: linux, git, permissions, gitlab

I am using Gitlab and try to trigger a very simple post-receive webhook in it which shall push the received commits to my webserver.

```
#!/bin/bash

git push develop develop

touch test_hook # just for test reasons
```

The `touch test_hook` is just for test reasons to see if the hook gets triggered. And it does. When I push something to my repo, the hook gets triggered and the test_hook file gets created / updated. But the push command is not executed.

I can't detect anything related in the `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log` file.
This is everything that appears in it when pushing:

```
time="2018-05-16T17:15:16+02:00" level=info msg="finished HTTP request" duration=0.040191547 method=POST pid=2175 url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v4/internal/allowed"
time="2018-05-16T17:15:16+02:00" level=info msg="executing git command" command="gitaly-receive-pack unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket {\"repository\":{\"storage_name\":\"default\",\"relative_path\":\"group/project.com.git\",\"git_object_directory\":\"\",\"git_alternate_object_directories\":[],\"gl_repository\":\"project-1\"},\"gl_repository\":\"project-1\",\"gl_id\":\"key-1\",\"gl_username\":\"username\"}" pid=2175 user="user with key key-1"
time="2018-05-16T17:15:17+02:00" level=info msg="finished HTTP request" duration=0.050373884 method=POST pid=2187 url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v4/internal/allowed"
time="2018-05-16T17:15:17+02:00" level=info msg="finished HTTP request" duration=0.00705723 method=POST pid=2187 url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v4/internal/pre_receive"
```

When I try to execute the push locally using the root user it works:

```
$ ssh root@my-gitlab.com 'cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/group/project.com.git ; git push develop develop'
To ssh://user@my-webserver.com/git-dir/project.com.git
  8fe2450..e48ed81  develop -> develop
```

When I try doing the same with the git user (as Gitlab should do it if I am right), it doesn't:

```
$ ssh git@my-gitlab.com 'cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/group/project.com.git ; git push develop develop'
GitLab: Disallowed command
```

So my guess is that the git user has no permissions executing `git push`. If I'm right, what's the reason for it? Can / Should I change it? If yes, how? If no, what would be a recommended alternative to execute the push with a webhook?